react-native ble manager connection errror
While trying to connect my React Native application to a Bluetooth device using the react-native-ble-manager library, I am encountering difficulties. Every time I attempt to connect to the device, the console displays the error message "Connection error." This indicates that the application is unable to complete the connection process with the previously paired Bluetooth device.
This is my code
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, PermissionsAndroid, Platform, NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-manager';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';


const ConnectDevice = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [isScanning, setScanning] = useState(false);
  const [bleDevices, setDevices] = useState([]);
  const [connectedDevice, setConnectedDevice] = useState(null); 
  const BleManagerModule = NativeModules.BleManager;
  const BleManagerEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(BleManagerModule)

  useEffect(() => {
    // requestPermissions();

    BleManager.start({showAlert: false}).then(() => {
      console.log('Module initialized');
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    BleManager.enableBluetooth()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Bluetooth is already enabled or the user confirmed');
        requestPermission()
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('The user refused to enable Bluetooth');
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let stopListener = BleManagerEmitter.addListener('BleManagerStopScan', () => {
        setScanning(false)
        handleGetConnectedDevices()
        console.log("Scan Stopped")
    })

    return () => stopListener.remove()
  }, [])

  const requestPermission = async () => {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    ]);

    if (granted){
        startScanning()
    }
  };

  const startScanning = () => {
    if (!isScanning){
        BleManager.scan([], 5, false).then(() => {
            console.log("Scan started");
            setScanning(true)
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
          })
    }
    
  }

  const handleGetConnectedDevices = () => {
    BleManager.getBondedPeripherals([]).then((bondedPeripheralsArray) => {
      console.log('Bonded devices:', bondedPeripheralsArray);
      if (bondedPeripheralsArray.length === 0) {
        console.log('No bonded peripherals found');
      } else {
        const devices = bondedPeripheralsArray.filter((device) => device.name); 
        setDevices(devices); // Update state with bonded devices
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(devices));
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error while retrieving bonded peripherals:', error);
    });
  }

  const connectToDevice = (device) => {
    console.log('Attempting to connect to device:', device);
    BleManager.connect(device.id)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to ' + device.name);
        setConnectedDevice(device); // Simpan perangkat yang terhubung
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Connection error', error);
      });
  };

  const disconnectFromDevice = () => {
    if (connectedDevice) {
      BleManager.disconnect(connectedDevice.id)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Disconnected from ' + connectedDevice.name);
          setConnectedDevice(null);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Disconnection error', error);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('No device connected');
    }
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.bleCard}>
        <Text style={styles.bleText}>{item.name || 'Unnamed device'}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => connectToDevice(item)}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>Connect</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };

   return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Perangkat terdekat yang tersedia</Text>
      {isScanning ? <Text>Mendeteksi ...</Text> : null}
      <FlatList
        data={bleDevices}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id || index.toString()}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button1} onPress={startScanning}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>Pindai ulang</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={disconnectFromDevice}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>Disconnect</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <View style={styles.containerMap}>
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: 'https://rinihsd.github.io/WebView-PRESISI/peta.html' }}
          style={styles.webView}
        />
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonsurvey} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SURVEI')}>
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>Survei</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

};


export default ConnectDevice;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    bleCard: {
      width: '100%',
      padding: 10,
      marginVertical: 10,
      backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
      elevation: 3,
      borderRadius: 5,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    bleText: {
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight:'bold',
    },
    button: {
      paddingVertical: 8,
      paddingHorizontal: 20,
      backgroundColor: '#17912b',
      borderRadius: 5,
    },
    button1: {
      paddingVertical: 8,
      paddingHorizontal: 20,
      backgroundColor: '#ccc',
      borderRadius: 5,
    },
    buttonsurvey: {
      paddingVertical: 8,
      paddingHorizontal: 20,
      backgroundColor: '#007BFF',
      borderRadius: 5,
    },
    btnText: {
      color: '#fff',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      textAlign: 'center'
    },
    containerMap: {
      height: 350,
      width: 370,
      marginTop: 20,
      marginBottom: 20,
    },
    webView: {
      flex: 1,
    },
});

Bluetooth Status Check: I ensured that Bluetooth on my device is active and that the device I want to connect to is also powered on and discoverable.
Device ID Verification: I added logging to check the device ID I am trying to connect to, ensuring that the ID is correct.
Permission Check: I have requested all necessary permissions to use Bluetooth, including permissions for scanning and connecting.
Disconnect Functionality: I implemented logic to disconnect from previously connected devices to ensure that no connections are improperly terminated.
Testing with Other Devices: I attempted to connect to other Bluetooth devices to determine whether the issue lies with a specific device or with the application itself.
I hope to resolve this issue and successfully connect my application to the Bluetooth device. I would like to receive solutions or further guidance on the steps needed to fix this connection error. Please help me i am newbie
